# Generate symmetric table in Android

Tags: android, tableview, row

I got some trouble with the TableLayout Android. I wanna create a table with symmetric rows/columns, i.e. a layout where every TextView in it gets allocated exactly the same amount of space like all the others, no matter what text has been appended to it.

It's important that this can be done by the use of Java-code, not the XML-files.

It would be probably good to know that this layout requires two tables to be next to each other, i.e. every table has just 50% of the screen size. I suppose this makes several LayoutParameter unavailable (e.g. FILL_PARENT)?

This is what I tried:

```
for (String s : buffer) {
            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            tv.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(0x00, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
            tv.append(s);       
            row.addView(tv, new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));   
        }
```

Still looks bad though.

Comment: basically, you set the size (width / height) to 0, and the weight to 1 for every item, and for every table row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will create two columns that share's the width in an orderly fashion.

```
<TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TableRow>
        <!-- Set the width to 0dp and set layout_weight=1! on both Views-->
        <TextView
            android:text="This is text1, its pretty long but that shouldn't be a problem"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1px"
            android:background="#ff0000"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Shorter"
            android:background="#00ff00"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

**Edit:** Same thing, but now in code:

```
    TableLayout layout = new TableLayout(this);
    TextView t1 = new TextView(this);
    t1.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    t1.setText("This is text1, its pretty long but that shouldn't be a problem");
    TextView t2 = new TextView(this);
    t2.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
    t2.setText("Shorter");

    TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
    row.addView(t1, new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
    row.addView(t2, new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));

    layout.addView(row);
```

Comment: I've got two problems with that: First of all of my programming is based on 2 seperate TableLayouts having adjusted each 50% of the screen. Second, I've absolutely no ideea how to set weight or margin (for the good look) in Java...

Comment: Well, 50% of the screen is 50% of the screen for both layouts - so they *should* still align. Adding another TableRow is "prettier" though. Adding code that does the same thing also should be trivial.

Comment: Yeah, I finally managed to use google, sorry. By using "tv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0x00, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));" on the TextView tv it actually should give it the very same parameters like in ur XML. Unfortunately it keeps looking crappy. I've added the whole code used for displaying in my post.

Comment: Dump a screenshot of your view & attach to the question?

Comment: I'm such a moron... I've added the LayoutParams to the TextView instead of the row. Thanks mate, looks beautiful right now!